# Side length of square inside a triangle

Tags: mathematics, geometry

What is the side length of a square that has a corner in both the right angle and on the hypotenuse of a right triangle with side lengths of three, four and five? Don't use a calculator!

Probably a pretty easy puzzle for some of you, but I thought it was fun to work out.

Answer (score 17):

[image]

> $a+b=5\\\therefore\frac5x=\frac{a+b}{x}=\frac{a}x+\frac{b}x=\frac54+\frac53$
> because the two smaller triangles are similar to the initial triangle
> $\therefore{x}=\frac1{\frac14+\frac13}=\frac{12}7$
>
> This also shows that in a right triangle with legs $m$ and $n$, the square will have a side length of $\frac1{\frac1m+\frac1n}=\frac{mn}{m+n}$.

Answer (score 8):

> Place the triangle so that its vertices are at $(0,0), (0,4), (3,0)$. Then the hypotenuse is $y=4(1-x/3)$. The corner of the square which lies on the hypotenuse is $(z,z)$ where $z=4(1-z/3)\Rightarrow 3z=12-4z\Rightarrow 7z=12$ so $z=12/7$ which is therefore the length of a side of the square.

Comment: is it coincidence $\frac{12}{7}=\frac{3\times4}{3+4}$?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry No -- and well spotted.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Perhaps it would be more obvious if the the hypotenuse was written as $4x+3y=12$.

Comment: @Neil; i don't understand?

Comment: @Neil Now we're getting into matters of style & opinion. Different people will look at the line & the coordinates of its intercepts on the axes, and they'll think of it in different ways. I saw the "y=mx+c" form; that comes naturally to me. When working on paper I wrote $y=4+\frac43x$ but took the factor 4 out when writing my answer. $4x+3y=12$ is also correct but perhaps doesn't leap so readily to the mind. Yet another way is $\frac{y}4+\frac{x}3=1$ which some might easily see -- it pairs each axis's letter with that same axis's intercept.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry As Rosie F said, it might be best to start with the equivalent formula $\frac{x}3+\frac{y}4=1$ (which readily generalises to any line through two points one on each axis). For the corner of the square of side $z$ to touch this line we need to have $x=y=z$. Solving these two equations is most readily achieved by multiplying though by $3\times4$ resulting in $(3+4)z=3\times4$ thus your fraction follows.

Answer (score 5):

A slightly different proof (which doesn't start with knowledge of the hypotenuse):

> we want the side of the square, call it $x$,
>  the area of the square is $x^2$,
>  the non-hypotenuse (two shortest) sides of the original, right-angled triangle are $a,b$
>  the area of the original triangle is, therefore, $\frac{ab}2$
>  removing the square leaves two smaller right-angled triangles (angles on a line sum to $180^\circ$)
>  they also have two shortest sides (meeting at the respective right-angle),
>  one of these sides of each of those triangles is a side of the square with length $x$,
>  the other of the sides are $a-x$ and $b-x$
>
>  [image: descriptive image of newly defined lengths and right-angles]
>
>  the sum of the areas of those two smaller triangles is\begin{align}&\frac{x(a-x)}2+\frac{x(b-x)}2\\=&\frac{x(a+b)}2-x^2\end{align}
>  the two smaller triangles and the square make up the whole of the original triangle so\begin{align}\frac{ab}2&=\frac{x(a+b)}2-x^2+x^2\\ab&=x(a+b)\\x&=\frac{ab}{a+b}\end{align}

Yielding an answer to the specific question posed of

> $\frac{3\times4}{3+4}=1\frac57$ (as already shown by others)

Comment: In what sense does this answer "start with knowledge of the hypotenuse"?

Comment: @PeregrineRook typo/B.F. :) doesn't - i.e. it proves the same without starting with and then cancelling out the hypotenuse.

Answer (score 3):

Using f'''s picture and Pythagoras, we get:

$$[1]\quad x^2+(3-x)^2=a^2\implies 2x^2-6x+9-a^2=0$$

$$[2]\quad x^2+(4-x)^2=b^2\implies 2x^2-8x+16-b^2=0$$

$$a+b=5$$

Adding $[1]$ and $[2]$ gives:

$$4x^2-14x+25-a^2-b^2=0$$

Using the fact the $x:a=5:4$ and $x:b=5:3$ we get:

$$\dfrac{x^2}{ab}=\dfrac{12}{25}\implies 2ab=\dfrac{25x^2}{6}$$

We know that:

$$25=(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+\frac{25x^2}{6}$$

So we have:

$$4x^2-14x+\dfrac{25x^2}{6}=0\implies \dfrac{49x}{6}-14=0\implies 7x=12$$

So $x=\dfrac{12}{7}$.

Answer (score 2):

This diagram was inspired by
[Jonathan Allan's generalization](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/40221/18129),
which shows that the hypotenuse length is coincidental, and by
[f'' ’s mention](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/40215/18129)
that the sides of the smaller triangle
are proportional to the sides of the full 3 × 4 triangle.
The underlying calculation speaks for itself simply.

> [image]

<sup>(Click within any spoilered/shaded region to show it permanently.)</sup>